# Exit form all modules in python

Tags: python, exit, spyder

I am writing a code in which there are various functions. I have created .py files for each specific function and I import them whenever needed. Example Code:

```
# main.py file
import addition
import subtraction
a = input("enter a")
b = input("enter b")
c = input("enter 1 to add 2 to subtract")
if a == 1:
    addition.add(a, b)  # call to add function in addition module
    subtraction.minus(a, b) # call to subtract function in subtraction module
# More code here

# addition.py module
import game # import another self-created module
y = input("do you want to play a game? Enter 1 if yes and 0 if no")
if y == 1:
    game.start()
# more similar code
```

Now, since you can see i am calling modules inside modules at multiple levels. So my question is in my `game` module, if I use exit command to end the code, will it end the whole execution or just the `game` module?
I need a command to exit from whole execution of code as and when i get some exception inside my code.

**NOTE**: I do not want the exit command to print anything on the console. As I had used sys.exit() once before in another project, it prints warnings on the console which I do not need as the project is for people who would not understand what that warning is.

Comment: If you want to terminate your application you can use ``sys.exit()`` - [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/constants.html#exit). Side note: you should consider to structure your code by using functions.

Comment: I have structured my code in functions too and it is working properly. But since my code is big of like 800 lines and more, I need to make a library for the same as it has different phases.

Comment: Also, sys.exit() prints warnings which i do not want to get printed on the console as the project is going to be for non-technical people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I use exit command to end the code, will it end the whole execution

Yes, it will (assuming you mean `sys.exit()`).

> or just the game module

No, it will exit the whole program.

Answer (score 2):

If you're worried that `sys.exit()` "prints warnings" (which I can not confirm on my system - the application just exists and no warning is printed in the console) you can just raise `SystemExit` with a message of your chosing:

```
raise SystemExit("Everything is fine.")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide warnings when program exits (this warnings are probably stack traces, hard to guess from your question) then you can wrap your code in try except block:

```
 import addition
 import subtraction
 try:   
    a = input("enter a")
    b = input("enter b")
    c = input("enter 1 to add 2 to subtract")
    if a == 1:
        addition.add(a, b)  # call to add function in addition module
        subtraction.minus(a, b) # call to subtract function in subtraction module
    # ...
except Exception:
    pass
```

Note that this technique is considered very bad and you should probably log your exceptions for example to file.

Ten inside your modules insend of user sys.exit() use this:

```
# addition.py module
import game # import another self-created module
y = input("do you want to play a game? Enter 1 if yes and 0 if no")
if y == 1:
    game.start()
# more similar code

# suppose you want to exit from here
# dont use sys.exit()
# use
raise Exception("Something went wrong")
```

## Finnaly log exceptions to file

```
import addition
import subtraction
import logging

# log to file
logging.basicConfig(filename='exceptions.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
try:
    a = input("enter a")
    b = input("enter b")
    c = input("enter 1 to add 2 to subtract")
    if a == 1:
        addition.add(a, b)  # call to add function in addition module
        subtraction.minus(a, b) # call to subtract function in subtraction module
    # ...
except Exception as e:
    logging.exception(e)
```

Using this your user will not see any messages on console when your program accidentally exits. You will be able to see what exceptions had occurred by reading excetions.log file.

## More info

- exceptions https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#exceptions
- logging https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html